# How to fix resolution that isn't accurate when using HDMI?

Tags: display, desktop, resolution, hdmi

I have machine running Loki that has both a VGA port and a display port. I'm using a 23 inch HDTV as my monitor and my resolution works fine when using the VGA port: 1920x1080.

However, when I try to use HDMI, the resolution is all messed up. Since my monitor only has HDMI and not display ports, I'm using one of [these cables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C9P9TM). The resolution still shows 1920x1080, but the top and bottom and a little of the sides are chopped off. It seems as though a simple auto adjustment from my monitor would fix this issue, but I am unable to auto adjust when using HDMI.

Has anyone else had these issues when using HDMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the display have overscan settings? Some TVs still crop the edges of the frame off, [due to a largely obsolete technology](http://www.howtogeek.com/252193/hdtv-overscan-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-probably-turn-it-off/).

Here is a Ubuntu discussion which may be of assistance:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv

You might be able to fix it on the TV, but basically either you get the TV to stop cropping the frame, or you get the computer to send a larger frame, just so the TV can crop it!!!

Yes, this is still a thing in 2017!!!